# Gatekeeper refuses validly signed application

Tags: macos, dmg, code-signing, gatekeeper

I am trying to publish a signed application, but when downloading it through internet, gatekeeper complains:

[image]

Furthermore, the help page says that the app has been tampered with: 

[image]

Which is actually not true, here is my signing/packaging procedure:

```
codesign --deep --force --verify -s "Developer ID Application: Nanolive SA (GMLD8K8WH3)" Steve/Steve.app
hdiutil create -volname Steve -srcfolder Steve -ov -format UDZO Steve.dmg
codesign -s "Developer ID Application: Nanolive SA (GMLD8K8WH3)" Steve.dmg
```

The whole procedure works without a problem, and as you can see, I don't change the package between the signature and the creation of the dmg.

I went through this whole document and I think everything is correct: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html

Furthermore, I went through everything in the `Checking Gatekeeper Conformance` section:

Checking the dmg:

```
$ spctl -a -t open --context context:primary-signature -v Steve.dmg
Steve.dmg: accepted
source=Developer ID
```

Using codesign:

```
$ codesign --verify --deep --strict --verbose=2 Steve.app
--prepared:/Volumes/Steve/Steve.app/Contents/MacOS/ffmpeg
--validated:/Volumes/Steve/Steve.app/Contents/MacOS/ffmpeg

<snip a lot of validated libs>

--prepared:/Volumes/Steve/Steve.app/Contents/Frameworks/libvtkRenderingAnnotation-7.1.1.dylib
--validated:/Volumes/Steve/Steve.app/Contents/Frameworks/libvtkRenderingAnnotation-7.1.1.dylib
Steve.app: valid on disk
Steve.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

using the `check-signature` tool:

```
$ /Volumes/Signature\ Check/check-signature Steve.app
(c) 2014 Apple Inc.  All rights reserved.
YES
$ /Volumes/Signature\ Check/check-signature Steve.app/Contents/Frameworks/*
(c) 2014 Apple Inc.  All rights reserved.
Steve.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtConcurrent.framework: YES

<snip a lot of YES>

Steve.app/Contents/Frameworks/qwt: YES
```

And lastly using `spctl`:

```
spctl -a -t exec -vv Steve.app
Steve.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: Nanolive SA (GMLD8K8WH3)
```

The command line tells me everything is 100% correct, but I still can't launch the app from the user interface because I'm missing something, somewhere, that the command line won't tell me.

Please note that when I bypass the quarantine using the command line, the app launches properly, which implies that I don't have any missing library as far as I'm aware.

The build server runs OSX High Sierra 10.13.6

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: If you go to Finder and then Applicstions, find your app and right-click it, then select Open, it will give you another button to let you bypass Gatekeeper. Have you tried that to see if the app can open at all?

Comment: Yes, it works fine if I do that.

Comment: Cool. So, at least you know it works and is just a cert issue.

Comment: Note that https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html is for 10.11 says look in Aplle Developer for up to date docs...... Current doc might be this one https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev033e997ca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## An `rpath` Problem

I was able to solve the issue thanks to some external help.

When opening the Console application, I was seeing this message, which comes from the XProtectService, which is apparently the real reference in terms of GateKeeper

```
default    11:00:31.445713 +0200    XprotectService    File /Volumes/Steve 2/Steve.app/Contents/MacOS/Steve failed on rPathCmd /Users/example/tmp/buildSteve/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/QtConcurrent
```

Which means that the issue was actually some bad `rpath`. The `rpath` is used to find and load frameworks needed by an application.

I wrote a [python script](https://gist.github.com/habfast/e1df628e9c77fc14ec1ef45269a87be9) to recursively fix the `rpath`, and now it works.

The script changes the executable's `rpath` using Apple's `install_name_tool`. This is not something user's should ever need to do and is exclusively something for an application's developer to fix before deployment.

Comment: Considering the entire solution seems to be the perl script I would suggest adding it to the answer :)

Comment: Please, share the python script with the fix, or explain it in further detail. Right now this is just a "Yay, I solved the problem" type of answer, doesn't really help without more information.

Comment: Actually the problem looks like a mounting disk issue. Your question calls the Value Steve and the answer `Steve 2` This is because at some time the disk unmounted incorrectly and left a directory around so the next mount created a new directory and thus chnage the path name

Comment: It's not a mounting disk issue: one you have your app ready to be packaged, you turn it into a dmg file using `hdiutil`, and you have to give it a name (in this case, `Steve`. Once you open the package, on a different computer, the first mounted dmg gets mounted to `/Volumes/Steve/`, and then the second to `/Volumes/Steve 2/` and so on. It's just the standard way mounting dmgs works on macs.